# Using awk to substitute with a literal backslash

Tags: shell-script, awk

I have an aws command that returns the following:

```
{
    "Parameter": {
        "Name": "/mysite/development/mongodb_uri",
        "Type": "SecureString",
        "Value": "mongodb+srv://administrator:mypassword@mongo-cluster-n1qub.mongodb.net/mysite_development?retryWrites=true&w=majority",
        "Version": 4
    }
}
```

I want to pipe it to awk and escape ampersands:

```
aws | awk '/Value/ { gsub(/[\",\"]/,\"\",\$2); gsub(/[\"&\"]/,\"\\\\&\",\$2); print \$2}'
```

The result looks like this:

```
mongodb+srv://administrator:mypassword@mongo-cluster-n1qub.mongodb.net/mysite_development?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

But the ampersand is not escaped. I expect "\&" in the resulting string. Note that this awk command is stored in a variable in a shell script which is being passed to eval.

```
AWS_COMMAND="aws ssm --region us-east-2 --with-decryption get-parameter --name"
AWK_COMMAND="awk '/Value/ { gsub(/[\",\"]/,\"\",\$2); gsub(/[\"&\"]/,\"\\\\&\",\$2); print \$2}'"

FETCH_AWS_SSM () {
  eval "$AWS_COMMAND /$APPLICATION/$DEPLOYMENT_GROUP_NAME/$1 | $AWK_COMMAND"
}

MONGODB_URI=$(FETCH_AWS_SSM "mongodb_uri")
echo MONGODB_URI
```

How can I get this literal backslash?

Comment: Can you provide the exact output you're expecting?  "question mark" is the "?" character, and has nothing to do with ampersand.  Providing the _exact_ input and _exact_ expected output (not just a substring) will help people understand the question.

Comment: @StephenHarris it was a typo. I meant to type ampersands

Answer (score 2):

If you're working with JSON, use a tool designed specifically for it, like [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/):

```
$ aws | jq -r '.Parameter.Value | gsub("&";"\\&")' 
mongodb+srv://administrator:mypassword@mongo-cluster-n1qub.mongodb.net/mysite_development?retryWrites=true\&w=majority
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't store commands in shell variables and then eval them, you're making coding much harder on yourself and introducing security concerns. Use functions instead, e.g. (untested):

```
AWS_COMMAND() {
    aws ssm --region us-east-2 --with-decryption get-parameter --name "$@"
}

AWK_COMMAND() {
    awk '/Value/ { gsub(/[,"]/,"",$2); gsub(/&/,"\\\\&",$2); print $2 }'
}

FETCH_AWS_SSM() {
    AWS_COMMAND "/$APPLICATION/$DEPLOYMENT_GROUP_NAME/$1" | AWK_COMMAND
}

MONGODB_URI=$(FETCH_AWS_SSM 'mongodb_uri')
printf '%s\n' "$MONGODB_URI"
```

but change all of the function and non-exported variable names to lower case (I just left them as you had them to emphasize the functional differences between the scripts) - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization